# bad auth : Authentication failed

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongoose, mern, nodemon

I am new to the MERN stack and I got this error.

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
bad auth : Authentication failed.
```

Here is my code  I tried changing the password, but couldn't help

```
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import cors from "cors";

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }));
app.use(cors());

const CONNETCION_URL =
  "mongodb+srv://myratcharyyev:<password>@cluster0.mn9xi.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

mongoose
  .connect(CONNETCION_URL, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
  .then(() =>
    app.listen([PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port : ${PORT}`)])
  )
  .catch((error) => console.log(error.message));

// mongoose.set("useFindAndModify", false);
```

Comment: Have you opened up for access from everywhere (IP whitelist) in Mongo Atlas settings?

Comment: Yes, still got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

```
const CONNETCION_URL =
  "mongodb+srv://myratcharyyev:<password>@cluster0.mn9xi.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
```

In the CONNETCION_URL do you change the `<password>` while running the code to the one you have set on the mongodb site